# When do I have to link libraries in C language?

Tags: c++, c

I'm new to C/C++ and I have this simple question. I don't know when I have to link libraries when I enter the command for the compilation. If I am right I'd add the parameter -l followed by the name of the library I want to include. But if I'm working for example with the math library of C, do I have add something like -lmath to compile my program? Or is it only necessary when you are using C external libraries as I read somewhere? What are C external libraries? Could anyone explain me this? thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most compilers will include the languages' standard libraries by default when linking.  gcc will include the C standard library (libc), and g++ will add the c++ standard library (libc++).  On some systems you may find yourself adding `-lm` for math, or `-lrt` for real-time extensions, but those libraries often add features outside the core language (though sometimes very commonly used features).

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Math is part of the standard library so you don't have to link it. Everything else should be linked.</strike> (EDIT: Not always true - check the comments below)

For example if you use in your code printf, strcmp, and pthread_create you don't have to link anything for printf and strcmp. Just include the right headers and you are ok. pthread_create however is not part of the standard library so you have to link to it - -lpthread.

Comment: Sometimes you have to link with math library to use standard math functions.

Comment: Okay, correct. I assumed he's talking about the functions in math.h, which as far as I know are part of the standard library.

Comment: On Solaris (for example) the math.h functions require linking in libm explicitly.

Comment: What does it mean "standard library"? Isn't "pthread_create" part of one of the libraries of the C compiler? Is "standard library" the opposite of "external library"?